# Debug Java application with Flash Builder 4.6

Tags: java, apache-flex, debugging, stateful

I have a Flex application with Java server. I have some stateless and stateful Java beans. I want to debug Flex side with Flash Builder 4.6.

Every debugging launch, my Java JSESSIONID is regenerated so I can't reload properly my stateful bean. This behaviour appears when debugging with standalone player, or web based debugging inside FB 4.6.

When I launch directly my application outside FB in a browser, JSESSIONID isn't regenerated as it should be but I can't debug...

Is there a trick to debug with FB without JSESSIONID being regenerated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the JSessionID relates to browser cookies which probably do not persist between browser sessions.  So, if you can configure your browser not to launch a new session every time a new window or tab is open that may work.

Other than that; you can hook up a Flash instance to a debugger session by right clicking on the Flash instance and selecting "Debugger".  [This answer tells you how to create the debug session w/o launching a browser instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1894238/133840).

To quote the relevant pieces:

> you can modify the launch configuration to refer to any URL that
>   doesn't contain a SWF; but I just wanted to add that you can also use
>   the URL "about:blank", which has the advantage that (as of Flash
>   Builder 4) Flash Builder won't even bother opening a browser page --
>   it will just start listening on the socket.

I use this approach a lot for debugging mouse and keyboard events from another computer.  One computer runs the app; and the other computer runs the debug session.

Comment: Thank you very much, with monitoring about:blank URL, it's work well.

Thank you again, I didn't know this trick

Comment: If you feel this answers your question, be sure to mark it as such.